# Help understanding IEnumerator Move routine

Tags: unity, c#, coroutines

I have this code and I know what it does (it will move an object up and down)

But I don't know how its elements work. Could someone please explain it to me?

```
IEnumerator Move (Vector3 Target) // What this IEnumerator do?
{
    while (Mathf.Abs ((Target - transform.localPosition).y) > 0.1f) {
        Vector3 Direction = Target.y == Top.y ? Vector3.up : Vector3.down;
        //Is this an if/else? and if yes why if target.y == top.y its first choice is vector3.up?

        transform.localPosition += Direction * 5 * Time.deltaTime;
        yield return null;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1f);
    Vector3 newTarget = Target.y ==Top.y ? Bottom : Top; 
    //Same line but result order is different ?.?

    StartCoroutine(Move(newTarget)); 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume the lines you don't understand are those you put comments on, so I will explain them in order.

1. A method returning an `IEnumerator` is one which can use the [`yield`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/yield)  instruction to return values to the caller. Whenever the program flow reaches a `yield`, the program flow goes back to the caller. The caller can then process that value and then resume the execution of the enumerator-method after the `yield` instruction (or not). When you encounter such a method in a Unity project, then it is usually used for a [Coroutine](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Coroutines.html). The `yield return`'s in a coroutine are the points where the program flow returns to the engine which will then resume the coroutine at a later time (how much later depends on what value you `yield return`).

   Unity Coroutines can be an elegant way to express processes which are supposed to take multiple frames to complete without having to add complicated state-determination logic to your `Update` methods or opening up the box of pandora which is actual multi-threading (I personally prefer state machines, command queues and behavior trees, but that's a personal preference).
2. The `a ? b : c` construct in C# is the [Ternary Condition Operator](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator). It returns a single value. If `a` is `true`, it returns `b`, otherwise it returns `c`. In this case `a` is `Target.y == Top.y`. So in plain English, this line means "If `Target.y` is equal `Top.y`, `Direction` is up, otherwise Direction is down".
3. And so, `Vector3 newTarget = Target.y ==Top.y ? Bottom : Top;` means "If `Target.y` is equal `Top.y`, then head towards `Bottom`, otherwise head towards `Top`"